# creating a filter in my spring mvc application using IDE

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea, servlet-filters

I'm trying to create a filter, for some reason I am not seeing autocompletion when I create a class that implements a Filter.

When I type:

```
import javax.servlet
```

IDEA doesn't seem to pickup the namespace.

Is this a separate .jar that I have to setup in maven?

**Update**

My filter mappings look like:

```
<filter>

        <filter-name>performancefilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.blah.core.filters.PerformanceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>performancefilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: In fact, you need the JAR file containing the Servlet API in the buildpath. This is usually shipped with the servletcontainer/appserver (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc). I only can't go in detail for IDEA+Maven2. In Eclipse without Maven2, you'd normally associate the webproject with an integrated server runtime and it goes automagically.

Comment: i'm running tomcat also locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a filter, for some reason I am not seeing autocompletion when I create a class that implements a Filter.

Then you probably don't have the `servlet-api` defined as dependency in your `pom.xml`. Assuming you're using Servlet 2.5, your `pom.xml` should declare:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks this worked!  btw, where can I see a simple skeleton of a filter with web.xml example?

Comment: @Blankman [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) is a good start (see [this](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=100) for the small changes since then).

Comment: funny, when I added the <filter></filter> xml in the web.xml, my </web-app> xml node is underlined in red (IDEA), not sure why.  It says content element <web-app> must match.  It does match! removing teh <filter>..</filter> tags gets rid of the error.

Comment: @Blankman Can't say without seeing all the relevant parts from the web.xml (except that you should probably use a wildcard in the url-pattern). Maybe open another question?